# TabHost nullpointer exception in android 2.2

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-tabhost, android-2.2-froyo, android-annotations

I'm trying to use a tabhost with 4 widgets, I've tested this on android 4.2 and it works like a charm, however on android 2.2 it gives me a nullpointerexception when I change tabs

I know there is a known problem with tabhosts and android 2.1/2.2 however I can't seem to get it to work with the other fixes people have suggested on other threads.

NOTE: I'm using [Android Annotations](http://androidannotations.org/)

Here's the LogCat :

```
03-23 10:29:08.869: E/AndroidRuntime(423): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-23 10:29:08.869: E/AndroidRuntime(423): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-23 10:29:08.869: E/AndroidRuntime(423):  at android.widget.TabWidget.focusCurrentTab(TabWidget.java:367)
03-23 10:29:08.869: E/AndroidRuntime(423):  at android.widget.TabHost.setCurrentTab(TabHost.java:320)
03-23 10:29:08.869: E/AndroidRuntime(423):  at android.widget.TabHost$2.onTabSelectionChanged(TabHost.java:129)
03-23 10:29:08.869: E/AndroidRuntime(423):  at android.widget.TabWidget$TabClickListener.onClick(TabWidget.java:453)
03-23 10:29:08.869: E/AndroidRuntime(423):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
03-23 10:29:08.869: E/AndroidRuntime(423):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
03-23 10:29:08.869: E/AndroidRuntime(423):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
03-23 10:29:08.869: E/AndroidRuntime(423):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-23 10:29:08.869: E/AndroidRuntime(423):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
03-23 10:29:08.869: E/AndroidRuntime(423):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
03-23 10:29:08.869: E/AndroidRuntime(423):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-23 10:29:08.869: E/AndroidRuntime(423):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
03-23 10:29:08.869: E/AndroidRuntime(423):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
03-23 10:29:08.869: E/AndroidRuntime(423):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
03-23 10:29:08.869: E/AndroidRuntime(423):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here's my code :

```
@NoTitle
@EActivity(R.layout.activity_base)
public class BaseActivity extends TabActivity {

    Context mContext;

    @ViewById
    Button btnBaseDeconnecter;

    @ViewById
    TextView txtBaseInfos;

    @AfterViews
    void afterViews() {
        mContext = this;
        TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();

        /* tid1 is firstTabSpec Id. Its used to access outside. */
        TabSpec firstTabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("0");
        TabSpec secondTabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("1");
        TabSpec thirdTabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("2");
        TabSpec fourthTabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("3");


        /* TabSpec setIndicator() is used to set name for the tab. */
        /* TabSpec setContent() is used to set content for a particular tab. */
        firstTabSpec.setIndicator(
                prepareTabView(mContext, getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.enlevement))).setContent(
                new Intent(this, EnlevementActivity_.class));
        secondTabSpec.setIndicator(
                prepareTabView(mContext, getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.travaux))).setContent(
                new Intent(this, TravauxListActivity_.class));
        thirdTabSpec.setIndicator(
                prepareTabView(mContext, getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.compte))).setContent(
                new Intent(this, CompteActivity_.class));
        fourthTabSpec.setIndicator(
                prepareTabView(mContext, getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.contact))).setContent(
                new Intent(this, ContactActivity_.class));
        tabHost.setup();
        /* Add tabSpec to the TabHost to display. */
        tabHost.addTab(firstTabSpec);
        tabHost.addTab(secondTabSpec);
        tabHost.addTab(thirdTabSpec);
        tabHost.addTab(fourthTabSpec);
        tabHost.getTabWidget().setStripEnabled(false);
        tabHost.getTabWidget().setDividerDrawable(R.drawable.empty_divider);


    }
    public static View prepareTabView(Context context, Drawable background) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.fake_native_tab, null);
        ImageView img = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.fakeNativeTabImageView);
        img.setImageDrawable(background);
        return view;
    }




}
```

Comment: is this exception happening whey you try to open a specific tab or when you try to open any tab or your four tabs?

Comment: It loads on the first tab when the app launches as you would expect, but if I click on the second tab it sends me to the third one and it's when I click on the third or fourth tab that it crashes

Comment: Precsions : it sends me to the third widget but to the second class

Comment: Try `tabHost.getTabWidget().setDividerDrawable(null);`.

Comment: that did it thanks, if you could put it into an answer so I can give you credit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `tabHost.getTabWidget().setDividerDrawable(null);` instead of `R.drawable.empty_divider`.

Reasoning:

Looking at the stacktrace and the [Android 2.2 source for TabWidget.java](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.2_r1.1/android/widget/TabWidget.java), there seems to be an issue in the `getChildTabViewAt(int index)` method where if the dividerDrawable is not null, it skips over the divider views in the tab bar to get the actual tabview.

```
public View getChildTabViewAt(int index) {
    // If we are using dividers, then instead of tab views at 0, 1, 2, ...
    // we have tab views at 0, 2, 4, ...
    if (mDividerDrawable != null) {
        index *= 2;
    }
    return getChildAt(index);
}
```

I think what happens when you use `R.drawable.empty_divider` for the dividerDrawable the divider views don't get drawn, so they should be treated as if they were `null`. As you can see, that doesn't happen, so that would explain the NullPointerException and the strange behaviour where you click one tab and it selects another.

Answer (score 0):

Use backword compatible library means add android.support.v4.jar in libs folder and try to use the same class from this library which will compatible with both lower and higher version

Comment: the android.support.v4.jar library doesn't contain a class TabHost or TabHostActivity